# changing a received file location in c# socket

Tags: c#

I have created a TCP server in c# which receives a file from a client and keeps it in the current directory. The code segment which does this is as follows:

```
       using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(Path.GetFileName(cmdFileName), FileMode.Create))
            {
                fStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                fStream.Flush();
                fStream.Close();
            }

        Console.WriteLine("File received and saved in " + Environment.CurrentDirectory);
```

where cmdFileName is the received filename.

Now I have created a folder named "test" inside the current directory using the following code:

```
            string root = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            string folder = Path.Combine(root,"test");
            if (!Directory.Exists(folder)) Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
```

I want to keep the received file inside the "test" folder. I need to make change to the following line of my previous code segment:

```
using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(Path.GetFileName(cmdFileName), FileMode.Create))
```

But what change will I have to make?

Comment: You just want to create a new file without overwriting the same file name?

Comment: I want to save the file I received from the client in the test folder, not in  the current directory @Some1Pr0

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Path.Combine` to get the path of the new `test` directory--you just need to use it again to find the path of the `cmdFileName` file inside the `test` directory:

```
string cmdFilePath = Path.Combine(folder, Path.GetFileName(cmdFileName));
using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(cmdFilePath, FileMode.Create))
```

Answer (score 0):

After this code:

```
string root = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
string folder = Path.Combine(root,"test");
if (!Directory.Exists(folder)) Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
```

Add another usage of the `Path.Combine` since you want to attach the path `folder` to the file `cmdFileName`:

```
string fullFilePath = Path.Combine(folder, Path.GetFileName(cmdFileName));
using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(fullFilePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    ...
}

Console.WriteLine("File received and saved in " + fullFilePath);
```

Also you should want to do it inside a `try` block in order to announce that it succeeded only if it really did:

```
try
{
    using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(fullFilePath, FileMode.Create)) //Exception accessing the file will prevent the console writing.
    {
        ...
    }
    Console.WriteLine("File received and saved in " + fullFilePath);
}
catch (...){...Console.WriteLine("Could not write to file " + fullFilePath);...}
```